# How to store a value on an address line?

Tags: lc3

I need help with figuring out how do I store the value of a register (e.g. R0) on an address line that can be found on yet another register (e.g. R1):

```
AddressLine[R1] <- M[R0]
if R1 = x3400
then x3400 <- M[R0]
```

Comment: I don't remember the opcodes anymore, but there is an opcode that will store the a register value into an address specified by a register. It is something like STR or STI R0, R1. Check the back cover of your book.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the STR instruction

```
STR <source register> <base register> <immediate offset>
```

i.e.

```
AND r0,r0,#0     ; clear r0
ADD r0,r0,#10    ; r0 = 10
LEA r1,MEMSPACE  ; address of MEMSPACE
STR r0,r1,#0     ; M[R1 + 0] = R0

MEMSPACE .word 0 ; will become 10
```